# My login form seems to have disappeared

Tags: blocks, 8, users

I'm developing a custom theme and even though I have placed the "user login" block in a region, I can't find it and now I'm locked out.

My site is on Drupal 8.

Comment: Have you tried going to something.com/user/login to login?

Answer (score 1):

The login block is "a" way to get logged in. Another solution to get loged in is to navigate to an URL like `/user/login`.

So try that, and see what happens then. Of course, if you get logged in, hurry to move that disappeared block to some region that for sure you now is OK. To QA test it, use another browser before logging out again ...

Comment: Thanks Pierre. But /user/login does not show the user form either.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that I dont have the block "main page content" enabled in any of the content regions. Could this be  problem?

Answer (score 1):

Phew!!. After hours of almost going crazy, I finally solved this by removing the custom theme from the theme directory. The default theme presented me with a login form and I'm back in. Thanks guys for help.